# How do I use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `allow_destroy` properly for integer fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Instead of checkboxes, I am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for integer input. I know that I can pass `_destroy` in the parameters (generally toggled with a checkbox) and `allow_destroy: true` will destroy the object.

According to the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for), `allow_destroy` only takes a boolean value and not a block.

How would I go about destroying the child object if the value of a parameter is `0` instead?

```
# event.rb
class Event
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :demands, allow_destroy: true
end

# _form.html.haml
= simple_form_for @event do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.simple_fields_for :demands do |builder|
    = builder.input :required, label: builder.object.role.name
  = f.submit
```

What's the best way to pass `_destroy` with a value of `true` if the `required` parameter of set to `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the "Rails Way" of doing things, but I have solved it with this:

```
class Event
  before_save :destroy_demands_if_zero
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :demands

  private

  def destroy_demands_if_zero
    demands.select{ |demand| demand.required.zero? }.map(&:mark_for_destruction)
  end
end
```

The key was [`#mark_for_destruction`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#method-i-mark_for_destruction).

Now when an event is saved, it will mark any chidlren (demands) with zero requirements to be deleted when the parent (event) is saved.